# Kendo grid details template and VueJS

Tags: vue.js, kendo-grid

I need to render a sub grid using Kendo UI. [Here is an example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/hierarchy/) from their site.

In their example, basically they construct the sub grid using jQuery, so I will lost the connection with my Vue component. In particular, that sub grid has to have some buttons to trigger other actions, like showing a modal and then removing some data.

I have a way to do this, but I want to know if there is any more "elegant" solution to my problem:

```
<script>
  var myComponent = {
    name: 'myComponent'
    data() {
      ...
    },
    methods: {
      test: function (data) {
        // here I do something with the data
      }
    }
  }

  export default myComponent
</script>
```

by defining myComponent as a variable first, I can access it from my kendo commands:

```
$('<div />').appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
  dataSource: e.data.someArray,
  columns: [
    {
      command: [
        {
          name: 'edit',
          click: function (e) {
            var data = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest('tr'))
            templatesManager.methods.test(data)  ---> HERE 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I don't like the approach of having a reference to my component, and as I don't have much experience with Vue, I want to know if this is the right way to communicate between the grid and my component. Unfortunately, we cannot get rid of Kendo Grid. [Here I found an example](https://medium.com/unbabel-dev/progressively-migrating-from-angularjs-to-vue-js-at-unbabel-581eb4ae022d) on how to connect between my vue component and AngularJS via events... is that a better option? this solution of having a reference to the component could cause any potential issues?